# Performance tweaks for a large static index?

Tags: elasticsearch

Our dataset is the following :

- About 8 millions documents. We do not expect massive changes. At most, 10 millions in the long term.
- 150GB storage for the primary shards
- Cluster : 5 data nodes with 16GB dedicated to ES, 8 cores and SSD
- 25 shards, 2 replicas

The documents are frequently updated, once a day on average.

The queries are pretty simple : geo and term(s) filters, mostly. 
The requested datasets are pretty large for ES standards (100 to 1000 documents requested for each search).

The request times are way slower than expected, with most requests taking more than 200ms. 
The monitoring tool shows that the nodes are perfectly fine :

[elasticsearch's cluster monitoring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5wQE.png)

Nodes configuration is standard. We only added `bootstrap.memory_lock: true` to the default setup.

What are the first steps in order to have faster searches ? The indexing time is not an issue. If faster searches means that the indexing time is slower, it's all good.

My first guess would be to play with the number of shards ? What else ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd do the following to narrow down/exclude possible cause of the problem:

1. Collect more stats for host/JVM, e.g. GC activity, IO stats etc. to see if there is anything suspicious.
2. Test without ingestion running to exclude indexing as the factor potentially affecting performance. If it helps - tweak indexing to reduce the overall load on the cluster, see [indexing optimization](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/tune-for-indexing-speed.html)
3. Try smaller result set, e.g. 10, from my experience using larger result sets may add noticeable latency.
4. Try [Profile API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/search-profile.html) for insights on where the time is spent, this may help to pinpoint problematic parts of a query which can be optimized.
5. Have a look at [search optimization](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/tune-for-search-speed.html) for general search performance tuning recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a quick calculation: 8 million docs create 150GB of data (primary shards), so an average doc size of ~19KB? If you get 1000 in the worst case, that's 19MB. I'm kind of surprised it only takes 200ms...

Is 200ms the time of `took` in the result set or is this on the client already? Anyway, it would be interesting to see how long the queries take for 10 results. And I wonder if you really need that many results that quickly.

And yes, your number of shards is a bit high (10 might be better or maybe even 5), though you'll need to test how much difference that actually makes.

Comment: Yes, 200ms is the `took` in the resultset.

The same queries with only 10 documents requested are much faster indeed, around 50ms. 

We will try lowering the number of shards, thanks for the advice.